# Pandas: set a default datetime for None values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with columns that contain dates as strings (in SQL-like format). However, many cells contain `None` values. I'm trying to convert these columns to Pandas dates using `to_datetime` and set a "default" value for cells that contain the `None` value. Example code below:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> d = {'a': [1,2,3],
        'd1': ['2016-01-01','2015-10-02',None],
        'd2': [None,'2016-04-03',None]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> print df
   a          d1          d2
0  1  2016-01-01        None
1  2  2015-10-02  2016-04-03
2  3        None        None


>>> date_cols = ['d1','d2']
>>> df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
>>> print df
   a         d1         d2
0  1 2016-01-01        NaT
1  2 2015-10-02 2016-04-03
2  3        NaT        NaT
```

It's simple enough to convert the valid strings to a date, I just want to replace the `NaT` with the `default_date`. This is what I'd like the final dataframe to look like:

```
>>> default_date = '2015-01-01'
>>> print df
   a         d1         d2
0  1 2016-01-01 2015-01-01
1  2 2015-10-02 2016-04-03
2  3 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
```

Comment: Calling `fillna` at the end does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `fillna`

```
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].fillna(pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'))
df
```

[image]